# WAP in java to find the mirror image of a ternary tree

Tags: algorithm, tree

Can any please give me an algorithm to find out the mirror image of a ternary tree?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just recursively swap the left and right children?

Pseudo-code:

```
mirror(node):
  if (node == null)
    return
  swap(node.left, node.right)
  mirror(node.left)
  mirror(node.centre)
  mirror(node.right)
```

Side note - except for the `mirror(node.centre)`, this is identical to the way to mirror a binary tree.